# How to create apple pay sandbox account and add card into wallet for testing apple pay

Tags: applepay, applepayjs, apple-wallet, applepay-web

I am facing an issue related to apple pay sandbox testing. I have followed all steps that mentioned on apple developer documentation for testing an apple pay on sandbox account.
Please can anyone guide me on below questions

1. How can I create sandbox account for apple pay?
2. How can I add testing card into Wallet on apple devices (MacBook Pro 2019)?

Can someone proper guide me related to this.

Thanks

I have followed all steps that mentioned on apple developer documentation for testing an apple pay on sandbox account but I am facing issues related to card adding into wallet. I have not seen any option related to wallet into my system settings on MacBook pro 2019.